# css animation change from absolute to relative

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i have found this wave animation "https://codepen.io/tedmcdo/pen/PqxKXg" and would like to use it over my headerimg on my page, but the problem is that the animation is written for absolute values, but i would need a relative position since the animation should stay on top of the page.

I have tried to change to position type to relative but however i do it i break the animation, if anyone could help me i would be happy^^

thank you all for your time.

here is the css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,254,234,1) 0%, rgba(255,254,234,1) 35%, rgba(254,208,149,1) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ocean { 
  height: 5%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background: #015871;
}

.wave {
  background: url(http://tedmcdo.com/labs/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -198px;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -175px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}

@keyframes swell {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you mean by this:

```
...need a relative position since the animation should stay on top of the page.
```

...but I digress.

Add a containing div with relative positioning

```
<div class="oceanContainer">
    <div class="ocean">
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.oceanContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100% /* you can play around with this for your header */
}
```

You may need to adjust some of the other CSS though

```
.ocean {
  height: 5%; /* as above, adjust to %, px, (r)em's to your liking */
  bottom: 0;
}

.wave {
  bottom: 0;    /* change top to bottom */
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 0;    /* change top to bottom */
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys with that help i could complete the wave.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a relative div(or other container), and the .ocean will be absolute in the relative container. That may solve your problem.

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <div class="ocean" style="position: absolute"></div>
</div>
```